# Jetpack Compose,I have multiple cards have scaffold inside, in a vertical scrollable column and if you don't give the card specific height it crashes

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, vertical-scrolling, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

In our application, there are many custom views that all are card with 3 slots header, content and bottom part, so I thought we can handle it with a scaffold inside the card except having many **if/else** conditions

So I created this base composable function ->

```
@Composable
fun DynamicTile(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    headContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    mainContent: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit = { },
    bottomContent: @Composable () -> Unit = { }
) {
    Card( modifier = modifier) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = headContent,
            content = mainContent,
            bottomBar = bottomContent
        )
    }
}
```

then different implementation for different purposes, I mention here two purposes
e.g. showing specific image, animation, map and ... ->

for this one you should add your local drawable to image to compile it

```
@Composable
fun TileTeaser( modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    with(entity) {
        DynamicTile(
//            modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.height(250.dp)),
            headContent = {
                Text(
                    text = "headline",
                   
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 8.dp)
                )
            },
            mainContent = {
                 val painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    data = painterResource(R.drawable.ds_ic_add))
                Image(
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    painter = painter,
                    modifier = modifier,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            },
            bottomContent = {
                     Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Button(
                        onClick = { }, modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Button")
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And this one for animation with Lottie, you should add local raw to compile it

```
@Composable
fun TileAnimation(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    DynamicTile(
        modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.height(300.dp)),
        headContent = {
            Text(
                text = "headline",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 8.dp)
            )
        },
        mainContent = {
            val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.sth))
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(183.dp)
                    .then(modifier),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
            ) {
                LottieAnimation(
                    composition = composition,
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                )
            }
        },
        bottomContent = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Button(
                    onClick = { }, modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .wrapContentSize()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Button")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Then I load them in column like this

```
@Composable
fun LoadScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        Text(text = "Teaser")

        TileTeaser(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
        )
        
        Text(
            text = "Animation",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
        )

        TileAnimation(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp))
    }
}
```

As you see if I comment the **Modifier.height** of the card,
it crashes with this error ->

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't represent a size of 2147483563 in Constraints
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion.bitsNeedForSize(Constraints.kt:408)
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion.createConstraints-Zbe2FdA$ui_unit_release(Constraints.kt:368)
```

Kotlin version 1.6.10 and compose 1.1.0 and this is lottie library ->

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:4.2.2"
```

BTW, you can download Lottie file from [here](https://lottiefiles.com/96036-bored-cat)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Scaffold is designed as a top level component. It fills max size by default. So I think putting it inside scrollable component is not possible without specifying its size directly.

Comment: @bylazy What do you think about this abstraction approach to make the custom view with scaffold ?

Comment: I would replace Scaffold with something more appropriate. In fact, you do not use its main advantages, such as dockable FAB or Snackbars. So, here it is just as layout. What you want to do, as I understand it, can easily be done with a Сolumn and three Rows inside.

Comment: @bylazy I got your point, you mean keep the DynamicTile func and replace scaffold with column and rows 
then I have multi slot API function and also no need to add fixed size to each card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Don't put a `Scaffold` inside a `Card` inside a scrollable content. :)

If we take a deeper look into `Scaffold` code we will see that it's actually creating a `ScaffoldLayout` that will create a `SubcomposeLayout` that uses constraints and more specifically the following width and height:

```
val layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth
val layoutHeight = constraints.maxHeight
```

Now, if no predefined values was set to the above `layoutWidth` and `layoutHeight` they will be equal to `Int.MAX_VALUE` which is 2147483647 which is what you see in your `IllegalArgumentException` (give or take).

When you use Scaffold the right way, usually as the root of your UI, Android do the magic for you and calculate the correct size.

My suggestion, replace the Scaffold with another type of layout or if it's not enough a custom layout:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/custom